# Modify original value type IEnumerable from .ToArray() reference

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

Basically I am trying to wrap a `IEnumerable` with a generic array and still be able to modify the values in the original collection, this works fine for reference types when I am just modifying their internal fields, but when using value types or trying to replace elements it does not appear to work.

For example:

```
// Original enumerable
var test = new List<int>(new int[] {
    1,
    2,
    3
});

// Array wrapper
var test2 = test.ToArray();
test2[0] = 100; // Does not change test[0]

// Don't want to use pointers, but as a test
unsafe
{
    int* test3 = &test2[0];
    *test3 = 100; // Still does not change test[0]
}
```

So I was wondering if there is someway to create an array wrapper of a value type `IEnumerable` that will allow the original collection values to be modified?

The reason I need to do this is the classes are being shared with FORTRAN95 code and due to limited compiler support for .NET arrays I can not anything that does not inherit from `System.Array`

Comment: @Selman22: isn't that the exact opposite of a deep copy? He wants the values to be referenced in both collections; a deep copy explicitly removes this reference.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel you right.. I don't know what was I thinking he needs shallow copy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Enumerable.ToArray()` doesn't "wrap" the enumerable in an array: it iterates over the enumerable, creating an array. It's pretty much the equivalent of this:

```
public static T[] ToArray<T>( this IEnumerable<T> source )
{
  List<T> list = new List<T>() ;

  foreach( T item in source )
  {
    list.Add(item) ;
  }

  T[] value = list.ToArray() ;
  return value ;
}
```

So if you do something like this:

```
int[] foo = PopulateSource() ;
int[] bar = foo.ToArray()    ; // Enumerable.ToArray()
```

saying

```
foo[3] = int.MinValue ;
```

won't affect `bar[3]` in the least, regardless of whether or not the array contains value types or reference types.

However, if you're using **reference** types,

```
Widget[] foo = PopulateSource() ;
Widget[] bar = foo.ToArray()    ; // Enumerable.ToArray()
```

and saying something like

```
foo[3].Gadget = new Gadget("Pancake Turner") ;
```

then the change will be reflected in both `foo[3]` and `bar[3]`, because both array slots are references to the same instance of `Widget`.

Further, you can't wrap something in an array, because even though `System.Array` is not `sealed`:

```
public abstract class Array :
  ICloneable, IList, ICollection, IEnumerable,
  IStructuralComparable, IStructuralEquatable
```

it is a special class and cannot be inherited from. So something like this:

```
class Widget : System.Array
{
}
```

Yields this compiler error

```
error CS0644: 'ConsoleApplication2.Program.Widget' cannot derive from special class 'System.Array'
```

What you can do is create a wrapper for your original object that gives array-like semantics, implementing `IList` and `IList<T>`.

Comment: Yeah I am asking if there is some kind of method or technique that will perform a shallow copy on value types as well as reference types, because from the code in my question it appears that it does a deep copy in the case of value types, any ideas? The only thing I can think of at the moment is creating an extension method that will copy the values of the original using pointers or something, but would rather not compile with /unsafe, thanks for the answer though

Comment: Edited my answer, sorry man, basically I need to use an array wrapper due to limited compiler support for .NET arrays.

Comment: `List<T>` has a `ToArray` instance method, so the LINQ extension method is not called in this case. It's documentation explicit states that it copies to contents to a new array.

Comment: @AlexHopeO'Connor: With references types, you can make a "shallow copy" of an array (since each array slot holds a *reference* to the actual object instance). With value types, each array slot holds the object itself: a shallow copy isn't possible, since you're cloning the object in each slot.

Comment: Cheers man, I'll mark as answer, not possible, will just work around it.